SQL - AD Security Group name changing in AD, effects?
I have been granting the permissions within SQL Server to an AD Group(Server-Level). If I change an AD security group name from "companyA_SQL_Server_DBA_Users" to "companyB_SQL_Server_DBA_Users".  Will it automatically be updated to "companyB_SQL_Server_DBA_Users", or will I get trouble?

Since authentication done by SID and not by name connection and permissions are fine. But the login name won't be renamed so it will be misleading.

https://serverfault.com/questions/1035668/ad-group-name-edited-but-sql-server-still-shows-old-name
